# How to measure the effect of the propellants to the thrust of the ion engines in a diy experiment?

Tags: experiment

I have a science project about how different propellants affect the thrust of an Ion engine. So I have 2 questions:

1. How can I measure the thrust of a diy ion engine? (technique or tool that I need to buy any solution is welcome)
2. Is there a way for me to test other propellants other than $N_2$ in the air (where to get the gases and a setup to test it)?

Any other suggestions to add value to my research is very welcome. Thanks.

The test ion engine will look something like the one shown [here](https://makezine.com/projects/ionic-thruster/).

Comment: Tie the engine to a strain gauge, or equivalent.

Comment: I suspect this should have been migrated to Engineering.SE, as this is not an astronomy **or** a spaceexplo question, but rather one of standard measurement tools and techniques.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Ion engines are used practically nowhere except space.

Comment: @peterh - that's as it may be;  they are not *tested* in space :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft [SMART-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART-1) flied to the Moon with an ion drive.

Comment: @peterh,  wow - an outfielder made a catch on the Moon?   All joking aside, you are missing the point -- nobody made a thrust measurement test on SMART-1 .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I would be really surprised if no testing of a completely new drive had happened before the launch. Well, I admit this test probably wasn't in the space, but in a vacuum chamber on the Earth. But it was obviously space technology development, and even a very cutting edge one.